# Notification in screen corner

Tags: c, linux, gnome

I need to create a small notification in the right-bottom corner of the screen. It should provide the following functionality:

- Should **NOT** change the current focus.
- Should allow me to put some text in it.
- Should appear (and stay if possible) on top of all windows.

Can you suggest using something? The less installing required the better.

Comment: Can you share which GUI environment you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are a few ways to do it.

- Roll your own
- Use the infrastructure of the desktop environment

Naturally, #2 is going to be more reliable — *if* you know what the desktop environment you're targeting is.

You mention Linux, so let's look at Gnome. The two most popular (?) Linux-based operating systems are the Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS family and Ubuntu, both of which are based on Gnome 3.

Gnome 3's Notifications;

- Do not change the keyboard focus
- Allow text (and more)
- Appear for a moment above other windows, but then tuck away at the bottom of the screen after a bit; but, can be called back up by mousing over their icons.

Plus, there's nothing to “install” — unless you're running an unusual build, the stock distributions all include the Notification support you want already.

The documentation is found [on the Developer.GNOME.org web site, here](http://developer-next.gnome.org/libnotify/0.7/).

If you are not running on a “normal” Linux distribution, you still have options.

- Install libnotify, and enough Gnome infrastructure to let it work.
- Re-inventing the wheel…

In the latter case, you'll want to:

- Create a top-level X Window;
- Set flags on it to ask the Window Manager to please* keep it on top, not decorate it
  with the usual resize and title decorations, and so forth;
- and set up its contents on your own.

Some documentation on providing hints to the window manager can be found on [FreeDesktop.org](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html).

*- the window manager, however, is free to ignore your hints, if it chooses.